# How about the "Certified Secure Software Lifecycle Professional"?

Tags: certify

I have invited to join Certified Secure Software Lifecycle Professional training course, however I have no idea about this course. Course's details give me only an overview of information, for example, this course is about how to gathering requirement about security, how to doing something in more secure ways etc.

Did anyone have experience about Certified Secure Software Lifecycle Professional? Is it worth to attend this course?

Comment: I'm divided on this subject.  As someone who hires people, I can tell you that the title sounds a little made-up.  But reading their website http://www.isc2.org/csslp/default.aspx it sounds like they have an idea.  Does it deserve a certification?  It sounds more like good engineering practice to me than a certification.